# Unable to install package via APT

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

While attempting to install the package `sw-nginx` I encountered the following error messages:

```
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/327 kB of archives.
After this operation, 813 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
sw-nginx
Authentication warning overridden.
(Reading database ... 149469 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking sw-nginx (from .../sw-nginx_1.6.0-1.14051516.debian70_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/sw-nginx_1.6.0-1.14051516.debian70_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/etc/logrotate.d/nginx', which is also in package nginx 1.6.2-1~wheezy
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/var/cache/apt/archives/sw-nginx_1.6.0-1.14051516.debian70_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to write (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/sw-nginx_1.6.0-1.14051516.debian70_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Error: An error occurred on attempt to install packages.
Attention! Your software might be inoperable.
Please, contact product technical support.
```

How can I install this package?

Comment: You're trying to install a package which has a file which conflicts with a file already installed and registered by another software package. The two packages are `sw-nginx` and `nginx`. A little investigation should suffice to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: My Debian installation has not heard of `sw-nginx`. What is the output of `apt-cache policy sw-nginx`? Or putting it differently, where did you get `sw-nginx` from?

Comment: This is part of Plesk repository.

Comment: Well, it is incompatible with `nginx`, so I suggest you remove `nginx` first.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out how to work around my issue by doing the installation like so:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite packagename
```

It would appear that I was getting collisions from a different `nginx` package that had files in common with this new package. I opted for the heavy handed method and simply did the above, `--force-overwrite`.

DO NOT USE :) Its useless it breaks it in another place...

Comment: Though this may look like it solved your issue, it's probably the lease liked method to use, since you essentially just smashed 2 packages together.

Comment: Using --force-anything if you don't know what you are doing is a bad idea.